# Is there a way stop bubble in javascript without "e" parameter?

Tags: javascript, parameters, event-bubbling

I have see a lot tutorial that tell me the way to prevent bubble is use "e" parameter

just like :

```
function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

but in some situation,the firebug tell me it is wrong with "e is not define"

so is there a way to stop the bubble without the parameter e?

Comment: please post relevant code that is breaking

Comment: e is just a variable name so you can refer to the event that is passed to the handler function - Firefox should only complain if no parameter name was specified by code that tried to reference it.

Comment: can you post the code that calls that? we can't tell from what you put what `e` actually is.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Something is stopping you getting the event object in the standard way. Rather then trying to avoid using it, you should find out why it isn't being passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set an event handler by using an element attribute (say, `<button onclick="myFunc()">`) the argument list will be empty. You have to use `<button onclick="myFunc(event)">` instead to pass the current event as an argument. No argument will be passed to the callback function by default.

`event` is a special variable in this case. When using `<element onEVENT="code">` the browser creates a new script and a function with the `FunctionBody` "code". This function will then take one argument `event`, thus you can use this object in your own function/code (see [w3c:ehca](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes)). Note that IE creates a global object `event` for every triggered event.

So pass `event` as an additional variable and use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) and [`e.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation). Note that `return false;` won't cancel the propagation in a `click` event.

Demonstrations:

- [Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yR6Mx/3/embedded/result/) showing the arguments of the callback function when using jQuery, `<element onclick="">` and `HTMLElementObject.onclick`.
- [`return false;` vs `e.stopPropagation();`](http://jsfiddle.net/PrPd4/embedded/result/) (spoiler: `return false;` fails.)

References:

- [W3C: DOM Level 3: `stopPropagation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopPropagation)
- [W3C: DOM Level 3: `preventDefault`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-preventDefault)
- [W3C: HTML5 Event handler content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes):

  > Using the script execution environment created above, create a function object (as defined in ECMAScript edition 5 section 13.2 Creating Function Objects), with:
  >
  > Parameter list FormalParameterList
  >
  > If the attribute is the onerror attribute of the Window object
  >
  > - Let the function have three arguments, named `event`, `source`, and `fileno`.
  >
  > Otherwise
  >
  > - Let the function have a single argument called `event`.