# recognize which span tag triggered javascript function in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div html element that has a click event set on it inline (not the way I want to do it but legacy code). See here

```
<div class="myDiv" onclick="triggerJavascript();" id="myDiv">

<span id="text1">Text 1<span>
<span id="text2">Text 2<span>
<span id="text3">Text 3<span>
<span id="text4">Text 4<span>
<span id="text5">Text 5<span>
```

What I want to do is recognize which span tag the click event originates from test5, then dont carry out the logic in triggerJavascript function, otherwise complete logic in triggerJavascript.

How can I set this up? I am working with jquery.

Comment: use event.target, or if u use jQuery use $(this)

Comment: Events callback functions are passed an `event` to them. One of the properties of the event object is a target. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target

Comment: span that is clicked is not past in the event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) in order to access the element. However, in order to get to this element you have to change your `onclick` attribute a little bit:

```
<div class="myDiv" onclick="triggerJavascript(event);" id="myDiv">
```

then you can access `event` in `triggerJavascript`:

```
function triggerJavascript(e){
   var element = e.target;
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766232/is-there-a-way-stop-bubble-in-javascript-without-e-parameter/9767971#9767971) for a more detailed explanation why `event` is needed.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfUWU/) ; [**Demo with text5 check**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfUWU/1/):

```
<script>function triggerJavascript(e){        
    if(e.target.id === "text5")
        alert("text 5 hit");
    e.stopPropagation();
}
</script>
<div class="myDiv" onclick="triggerJavascript(event);" id="myDiv">
    <span id="text1">Text 1</span> <!-- closing tags -->
    <span id="text2">Text 2</span>
    <span id="text3">Text 3</span>
    <span id="text4">Text 4</span>
    <span id="text5">Text 5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @amateur: You forgot to close your `<span>` elements. You have only open tags, but not any closing tag. Also note that `triggerJavascript` needs to be defined *before* the actual DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `onclick="triggerJavascript();"`, or the event target (the span which was clicked) will not be passed to the event handler.

Since you state you're using jQuery, use this:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(evt) {
    alert("The target is: " + evt.target.id);
});
```

Comment: You can use `onclick="triggerJavascript(event);"` to pass the event object, see also http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes.

Comment: I know, but I wouldn't encourage that.

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<div class="myDiv" onclick="triggerJavascript(event);" id="myDiv">
  <span id="text1">Text 1<span>
  <span id="text2">Text 2<span>
  <span id="text3">Text 3<span>
  <span id="text4">Text 4<span>
  <span id="text5">Text 5<span>
</div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function triggerJavascript(event) {
      // event.target will catch the clicked element
      if (event.target.id !== 'text5') {
          // do something
      }
   }
</script>
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J7FGv/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the HTML, you could try something like this:

```
var triggerJavascript = (function(){
    var clicked;
    $("#myDiv span").click(function(e){
        clicked = $(e.target).attr("id");
    });
    return function() {
        if (clicked == "text5") {
            return;
        }
        //do something cool...
    }
})();
```

Although I guess, there's no guarantee that the jQuery click handler is executed before the actual `triggerJavascript` logic, so this might not always work correctly.